# Simulation of DFIG input voltage to stator

Tags: power-electronics, generator, induction-motor, simulink, power-generation

I'm currently looking into the modelling of a DFIG in simulink (however I have seen models in other programs as well) and I'm slightly confused as to why there is a 3-phase voltage input to the stator (for example from this source: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57441-dfig-wind-turbine-model?s_tid=srchtitle). I have also seen this input in literature around DFIG simulation and other models.

I'm not trying to make this too much of a simulation/question, however from my understanding I don't know why there is an input voltage to the stator. There should be active power from the stator to the grid and there would need to be current supplied to the rotor for magnetisation to then induce a voltage.

Apologies if this purely pertains to simulink however I was just looking for any clarification on the above issue from the general operation of a DFIG; and/or whether my analysis is correct. Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the back of this, just had a thought now: is the voltage being applied perhaps the output from the rotor to the stator? i.e Ur in this picture: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohammed_Saci_Chabani/publication/321816932/figure/download/fig1/AS:648613684318217@1531652961795/Block-diagram-of-the-autonomous-WECS-based-on-DFIG.png

Comment: I'm not sure about this picture however as the power fed to the generator should be from the grid and the rotor aspect (i.e Ur) should be feeding the grid